# Can't define the matrix_double3x3 in a c header

Tags: swift, xcode, metal

[image]

I tried to define the matrix_double3x3 properties but the compiler don't allow me to do.
I can define the matrix_float3x3 or matrix_half3x3 but not for the matrix_double3x3.

[image]

But I saw the `matrix_types.h`, it has `typedef simd_double3x3 matrix_double3x3`

My goal is to send the `matrix_double3x3` to Metal for computing the rectified image.

#### Environment

- Xcode 14.0 (14A309)

  - Destination:

    - macOS (Minimum Deployments: 12.3)
- macOS 12.6 (21G115)

Comment: You can't use double precision floating point numbers in Metal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to documentation https://developer.apple.com/metal/Metal-Shading-Language-Specification.pdf:

> Metal does not support the double, long long, unsigned long long, and
> long double data types.

It means you can implement double simd in host code, not in MSL.

However, if you need to improve the accuracy of calculations you can try to test the project: https://github.com/BrianSwift/MetalQD